# How to use select statement with where condition on node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql

[image]>  Am trying to provide login credentials with email and password using postgres database table.

> postgres database tables. When i get records it should send 200 status
>   to my page.Am getting error on query. Kindly help me out how to use
>   select with where condition. Am missing some syntax.

```
     getUser : function(req, res) {    
        var pg = require('pg');    
        var conString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || "postgres://test:test@localhost:5432/wallet";
        var client = new pg.Client(conString);  
          client.connect();

             console.log(req.query.email_id);
             console.log(req.query.user_password);
            var query = client.query("select * from pp_user_profile where email_id ="+req.query.email_id+ "and" + "user_password=" +req.query.password);

            query.on("end", function (result) {          
                client.end();
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                res.write('Success');
                res.end();  
            }); 

  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below syntax:

```
"select * from pp_user_profile where email_id  = '"+req.query.email_id+"' and user_password= '"+req.query.password+"'";
```

Comment: @Varathan Swaminath glad to help ypu. have a happy coding.. Please accept the answer if it really helped you..